# Gitlab Releases and Patches

Tags: git, gitlab, branch

The release functionality in Gitlab seems nice, but I cannot find any documents on how you can patch a release down the line (and integrate the changes back into the main branch)

I know it tags the main branch, is this how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [GitLab release](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/) enables you to create a snapshot of your project for your users, including installation packages and release notes. You can create a GitLab release on any branch. Creating a release also creates a Git tag to mark the release point in the source code.

Patching a release is essentially fixing bugs or adding enhancements to an already released version of the code.
Ideally, you would create a separate branch to prepare/code that path, then create a merge request to merge the patch branch back into the branch from your original release.

From there, you can create a tag, and a new release, once the MR (Merge Request) was accepted.

You can also do an MR of the same changes back to main.